# Sending HTTP request via command line and curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl, ddns

I am running a cloud server on a raspberry pi (raspian) and like to tell my host the ip adress. To this end, the provider of my URL provides an API which works by sending:

`https://<provider_url>/upd.php?user=<username>&pwd=<pwd>&host=<hostname>`

If I enter this into the browser (with the correct parameters, obviously), I  get the message "Hostname updated."

To automate this process, I'd like to do the same via the command line. After reading about the  `curl` command I tried

`curl --data "user=<username>&pwd=<pwd>&host=<hostname>" https://<provider_url>/upd.php`

as the string given by `--data` is supposed to be appended to the URL with an '?' and every argument separated by '&'. However, I receive error messages on 'inv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as the string given by `--data` is supposed to be appended to the URL with an `?`

You're missing this [emphasis mine]:

> `-d`, `--data <data>`
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a **POST** request to the HTTP server […]
>
> `-G`, `--get`
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with `-d`, `--data`, `--data-binary` or `--data-urlencode` to be used in an HTTP **GET request instead of the POST request** that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a `?` separator.

<sup>[(source)](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)</sup>

Using the whole original string as a URL should also work. Mind the quotes:

```
curl 'https://<provider_url>/upd.php?user=<username>&pwd=<pwd>&host=<hostname>'
```